# Seeking a mechanism to hang a MacBook Pro from desk

Tags: macbook-pro

I'd like to find a way to hang my MacBook Pro from my desk in a way that makes it easy to connect to my monitor and to the peripherals.

I've seen the [Twelve South BookArc Stand for MacBook](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HP9Y2ZM/A/twelve-south-bookarc-stand-for-macbook), but I'd prefer something that doesn't consume desktop space.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the caliper to make one DIY? Here is a great idea from DIY Perks (a well-known youtube channel with fantastic ideas): https://youtu.be/tGX34631pdk. It takes some skill and materials, but overall, it isn't too hard.

**FULL Disclusure: I have not created or used this before.**

Comment: Interesting idea.  It would need to be adapted a bit to handle the 2-sized, port arrangement of the MBP.

Comment: @craig Isn't the only port necessary a usb c/thunderbolt port (charging, displays, & peripherals via a dock)?

Comment: If you want to have two monitors and power, then both sides need to be exposed.

Comment: @craig how come? I believe you can drive 2 monitors & charge over 1 port using a dock. And both the old 13 inch & the newer 14 & 16in have at least 2 usbc ports on one side, so even if it needs 2 c ports, this should be possible via one side.

Answer (score 1):

I have two articulating arms on my computer desk at work. One arm has a 27" BenQ monitor attached to it, the other uses this [Laptop VESA Mount tray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WW8NVTK) to hold my MBP above my desk to provide space underneath on my desktop. There are other manufacturers which have similar trays for sale. You could purchase a double [articulating arm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HSJN0HK) and using the tray, accomplish what you want if the external monitor has VESA mounting holes (and most of them do.)

I highly recommend this solution, no matter what equipment you purchase. I use a wireless mouse & keyboard, making the whole setup pretty slick!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your monitor has standard VESA mounting holes, you could attach something like this [StarTech.com Thin Client Mount](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076N6B6GQ).

[image: Product photo of NUC computer mounted to between a monitor and monitor arm]

Comment: OP is looking to suspend the MBP over the desk, not a monitor.

Comment: I suggested this solution to a friend for his company's Windows computers.  Worked well for that usage-case.